# How to query a map of id with graphql?

Tags: graphql

I am trying to query an array of ids with graphQl. The query works with a single id as a variable. However it doesn't work when I enter an array of ids.
Here is my gql query with variables:

```
query GetAuthorContent($id: [ID]!, $idType: AuthorIdType) {
  expert(id: $id, idType: $idType) {
    excerpt
    featuredImage {
      node {
        description
        author {
          node {
            description
          }
        }
      }
    }
    slug
  }
}

{"id": ["author-1", "author-2", "author-3"], "idType": "SLUG" }
```

Comment: The service needs to support querying for multiple IDs.

Comment: what is the Graphql endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the definition of the graphql endpoint using a client and see if the Arrays are supported with query.

If it's supported, check the mutation signature and pass accordingly. In this case I think the services does not support querying using an Array.

Answer (score 1):

Hi everyone and thank you for your help.
You guys were right, my DB doesn't allow an array of authors if it is per autho***r*** singular. However it works with author***s*** plural. This is the way my db works.

Hope it can help someone in the same situation.